# Dequeue/deregister css and js for backend

Tags: javascript, css, woocommerce

I am struggling with this one, but what I am looking to do is speed up the WooCommerce backend. I am at around the 10 second mark and I am looking to shave off a few seconds by eliminating any unneeded scripts and css that are getting loaded.

I am only looking to eliminate these requests in the backend, specifically the orders page and single orders page of WooCommerce. I toyed with placing `add_action` above and below the function, but nothing.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_admin_styles', 999 );
function remove_admin_styles()
{

    // Dequeue
    wp_dequeue_style( 'caldera-forms-admin-icon-styles' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'et-core-admin' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'et-core-portability' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wf-common-style' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wf-fedex-style' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommercebulkdiscount-style-admin' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'tm_epo_admin_css' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'tc-font-awesome' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'tm_global_epo_animate_css' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'tm_global_epo_admin_css' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'tm_global_epo_admin_font' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'tm-spectrum' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'tc-font-awesome' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'yoast-seo-admin-global' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'yoast-seo-dismissible' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'et-meta-box-style' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'et-core-version-rollback' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'library-menu-styles' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_admin_menu_styles' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_admin_styles' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'yoast-seo-toggle-switch' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'yoast-seo-admin-css' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce-activation' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'dashicons' );


    // Deregister 
    wp_deregister_style( 'caldera-forms-admin-icon-styles' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'et-core-admin' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'et-core-portability' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'wf-common-style' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'wf-fedex-style' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'woocommercebulkdiscount-style-admin' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'tm_epo_admin_css' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'tc-font-awesome' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'tm_global_epo_animate_css' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'tm_global_epo_admin_css' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'tm_global_epo_admin_font' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'tm-spectrum' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'tc-font-awesome' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'yoast-seo-admin-global' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'yoast-seo-dismissible' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'et-meta-box-style' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'et-core-version-rollback' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'library-menu-styles' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'woocommerce_admin_menu_styles' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'woocommerce_admin_styles' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'yoast-seo-toggle-switch' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'yoast-seo-admin-css' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'woocommerce-activation' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'dashicons' );
}
```

Comment: Made a mistake in my answer. Instead of `wp_print_styles` you need `admin_print_styles`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hook `admin_init` is executed before `admin_enqueue_scripts` (when admin styles are enqueued). That means they get enqueued anyway.

Use `admin_print_styles` as your hook. By having the priority high at 1 (the last argument of `add_action()`) you make sure it gets executed before the styles get printed.

See the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_print_styles)

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'remove_admin_styles', 1 );
function remove_admin_styles()
{

    // Dequeue
    wp_dequeue_style( 'caldera-forms-admin-icon-styles' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'et-core-admin' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'et-core-portability' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wf-common-style' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wf-fedex-style' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommercebulkdiscount-style-admin' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'tm_epo_admin_css' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'tc-font-awesome' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'tm_global_epo_animate_css' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'tm_global_epo_admin_css' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'tm_global_epo_admin_font' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'tm-spectrum' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'tc-font-awesome' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'yoast-seo-admin-global' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'yoast-seo-dismissible' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'et-meta-box-style' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'et-core-version-rollback' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'library-menu-styles' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_admin_menu_styles' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_admin_styles' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'yoast-seo-toggle-switch' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'yoast-seo-admin-css' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce-activation' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'dashicons' );


    // Deregister
    wp_deregister_style( 'caldera-forms-admin-icon-styles' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'et-core-admin' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'et-core-portability' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'wf-common-style' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'wf-fedex-style' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'woocommercebulkdiscount-style-admin' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'tm_epo_admin_css' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'tc-font-awesome' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'tm_global_epo_animate_css' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'tm_global_epo_admin_css' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'tm_global_epo_admin_font' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'tm-spectrum' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'tc-font-awesome' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'yoast-seo-admin-global' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'yoast-seo-dismissible' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'et-meta-box-style' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'et-core-version-rollback' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'library-menu-styles' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'woocommerce_admin_menu_styles' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'woocommerce_admin_styles' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'yoast-seo-toggle-switch' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'yoast-seo-admin-css' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'woocommerce-activation' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'dashicons' );

}
```

Comment: Not sure that this is best practice: "Note
admin_print_styles should not be used to enqueue styles or scripts on the admin pages. Use admin_enqueue_scripts instead." - https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_print_styles

Comment: @user10161674 you don't `enqueue` them, but `dequeue` them! That is why you do it before they get printed but after they got enqueued. (otherwise they would be enqueued anyway.)

Comment: @user10161674 I ajusted my answer a bit

Comment: @user10161674 the last argument is 1 for highest priority. I tested my answer and it works!

Comment: My guess is that css files are not to blame for your long loading times. Take a look at Inspector to see what takes the most time in loading your page

Comment: Between js and css, it was. I do have the solution that above working and I am down about a 4.5 second page load on the backend for Woo orders. a great improvement. There are just too many plugins running on this site.

Comment: Thanks so much @jrswgtr